# Comparar string PANDAS Data Science

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ipython-notebook

Estou começando nesse mundo de data Science e minha duvida como posso compara duas string na mesma coluna.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma coluna [Investigation Type] que tem 'Acidente' e 'Incidente' eu queria fazer comparação entre as duas com grafico e não estou conseguindo.
como eu poderia fazer essa comparação com pandas?

Comment: Não entendi bem a pergunta. Que comparação gostaria de fazer? Contar as ocorrências de `Acidente` e `Incidente`?

Answer (score 0):

Se a comparação é ver o número de ocorrências de cada tipo, `Acidente` e `Incidente`, e plotar um gráfico de barras, é possível usar a função [hist](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) do próprio pandas:

```
df['Investigation Type'].hist()
```

Mas eu particularmente acho o gráfico do matplotlib mais bonito:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = df['Investigation_Type'].unique() #['Acidente', 'Incidente']
# Também é possível pegar valores específicos fazendo: x = ['Acidente', 'Incidente']
y = [df['Investigation_Type'].value_counts()[key] for key in x]

plt.bar(x, y)
```